# ListPlot python generated data from a text file

Tags: plotting, import, data

I have an issue plotting the following data using `ListPlot`. Could you please check what this issue is?

```
1.000000000000000021e-02,5.098124272448313121e+00
1.007072300075525194e-02,5.095599438856259766e+00
1.014194617579408653e-02,5.093058220475524145e+00
1.021367306249912864e-02,5.090500521354407226e+00
1.028590722327043204e-02,5.087926245125546920e+00
1.035865224570241272e-02,5.085335295006411904e+00
1.043191174276203274e-02,5.082727573799598275e+00
```

This is part of a data set stored in a .txt file that has been generated using python.

Thanks!

Comment: I voted to close this post because no explicit question is stated, and no description of the "issue" is given.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I pasted this data into a text file, imported it in and plotted it. The result can be seen as a comment under the answer by @JasonB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data looks like a CSV format, so to make a Mathematica expression use `ImportString` (or `Import` if your data is in a file):

```
data = ImportString[
   "1.000000000000000021e-02,5.098124272448313121e+00
1.007072300075525194e-02,5.095599438856259766e+00
1.014194617579408653e-02,5.093058220475524145e+00
1.021367306249912864e-02,5.090500521354407226e+00
1.028590722327043204e-02,5.087926245125546920e+00
1.035865224570241272e-02,5.085335295006411904e+00
1.043191174276203274e-02,5.082727573799598275e+00
", "CSV"];
ListPlot[data]
```

Comment: data1=ImportString["C:\\ABC\\Folder\\data.dat", "CSV"] and then ListPlot[data1].  This still doesn't work.

Comment: `ImportString` is for when you have the contents of a file as a string, like in the example here.  It interprets the first argument as actually being the data.  You want to use `Import`, which interprets the first argument as being a file name.

Comment: Ok, but I tried first with Import also and still doesn't work. Do you mean I should first import the data with Import and then use ImportString?

Comment: `data = Import["C:/data.txt", "CSV"]` and `ListPlot[data]` gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I01o9.png).